# Flicker on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flicker

I have a problem regarding a flicker when changing from absolute to fixed with Javascript. I can't reproduce the problem in Mozilla Firefox, however, both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome have the problem. I can't seem to fix it.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css">

    <script src="plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jqueryUI.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/transit.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/centering.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <title>Interdomein</title>
</head>

    <div id="mainMenu">     
        <div class="button" style="margin-left: 88px;"> Home        </div> 
        <div class="button">                                Webhosting  </div>
        <div class="button">                                Domeinen    </div>
        <div class="button">                                Support     </div>
        <div class="button">                                Contact     </div>
        <div class="button">                                Inloggen    </div>
    </div>

<body>  

    <div id="header">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

body    {
    background-color: black;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
}

#mainMenu   {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}

.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-left: black 1px solid;
    border-right: black 1px solid;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function()  {

    $(window).scroll(fixMenu);
    fixMenu();

});

function fixMenu() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $( "#mainMenu" )      .css( "position", "fixed" );
        $( "#mainMenu" )      .stop(1,0).transition({ width: 50 },1000);     
        $( ".button" )        .hide();
    }
    else    {
        $( "#mainMenu" )      .stop(1,0).transition({ width: 900 },250);
        setTimeout(function(){  $( ".button" ).show()  },250);
        $( "#mainMenu" )      .css( "position", "absolute" );
    }
}
```

For a working example, see "interdomein.site11.com". This adress will change over time, but for the next 24 hours it will probably be like this.

Comment: I can't notice any flicker, maybe its just me :/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m, Windows 7 64bit. Exactly where the flicker happens?

Comment: Strange. I'm using the same setup, with a flicker at the menu bar. It only happens when you scroll down from the top.

Comment: well, it could be your hardware or a slow/overloaded system? Honestly i am not very sure...

Comment: I'm having it here, at my school pc. But I don't have the problem with firefox. I also have never experienced it before. I also experience it at my gaming pc at home.

Comment: Because you are using transitions, perhaps it is a hardware acceleration bug.  I think it is more common for webkit browsers (older ones?).  I was actually just reading a blog about is... mybe this link will help?http://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/

Comment: Note that `will-change` is a) experimental, so its browser support isn't uniform; and b) advisory, meaning you can't rely on explicit behavior in any given circumstance. That said, it's always fun to play with. :)